# Django-admin inline default value

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-admin

*admin.py*

```
class CaseNoteInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CaseNote
    form = CaseNoteInlineForm
    extra = 1
    max_num = 5
    readonly_fields = ['User']


    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'User':
            kwargs['initial'] = request.user.id
            return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
        return super(CaseNoteInline, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(
            db_field, request, **kwargs
        )
```

i have a some column in CaseNote which is "User" and i want to set default value for that. [image: just i want to initiate this selectbox]

Comment: you have to use form for admin.

Comment: class CaseNoteInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = CaseNote

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        initial = kwargs.pop('initial', {})
        initial['User'] = initial.get('User', 1)
        kwargs['initial'] = initial
        super(CaseNoteInlineForm, self).__init__(
            *args, **kwargs
        ) now i just need to set user and i tried to request.user but its not working :S

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5633629/2282638

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4764294/2282638